# What is the differance between "Out of Syllabus" and "Beyond Syllabus"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Please let me know that "What is the difference between "**Out of Syllabus**" and "**Beyond Syllabus**"?"

For example; **This question is out of syllabus.** Whether the Question is from the course curriculum or it is not from the course curriculum?

Comment: Who said/wrote this? What is the context? Please [edit] additional information into your question.

Answer (score 4):

In both the cases, the questions are *not* from the syllabus. For instance, if the test is on the cardiovascular system and you find a question on the muscle attachment of a bone, that would be considered *out of syllabus.* Why? Because the test was for *cardiovascular* and not *skeletal* system.

Anything beyond is *exceeding* the limits. I've heard *out of...* more than *beyond...* in the context of syllabus.

Comment: Beyond the syllabus could mean "at a higher level", If the course was "introduction to calculus" and there was a question on abstract measure theory, you could say that was beyond the syllabus.

Answer (score 3):

Out of syllabus means teaching a different topic which is not in the prescribed syllabus. Beyond the syllabus means to extend the understanding of a particular concept (from the syllabus) beyond the confines of the text.

Comment: Hello Michelle, thanks for this contribution.  Please take a look at some of our more recent questions (as this one is now more than two years old)

Answer (score -2):

*Out of syllabus* means from the prescribed syllabus course. (That is, related to the prescribed syllabus course.)

*Beyond syllabus* means not from the prescribed syllabus course. (That is, not related to the prescribed syllabus course.)

Comment: _Out of [the] syllabus_ could mean "pulled out from the syllabus", as you suggest, but it could also mean "outside of the syllabus". So _beyond syllabus_ and _out of syllabus_ could be synonyms or antonyms, depending on which meaning of "out" was intended.